# Python: assign variable and ignore 'IndexError'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python code that searchs for a string in a list and stores the corresponding parameter to a variable.

Below 'X' has lists separated by commas in singles quotes, my actual logic `map1 = str(val).split('MAP:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()`  search for `MAP:` and store the corresponding parameter `A` into `map1` variable.

```
X = [
    'sequence:1, MAP:A, num1:1, num2:2, num3:3',
    'sequence:2, num1:10, num2:20, MAP:B, num3:30',
]

Y = []
for val in X:
    map1 = str(val).split('MAP:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
    num1 = str(val).split('num1:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
    Y.append(['VEQ','1',map1,'2',num1])
print(Y)
```

#### Output

```
[['VEQ', '1', 'A', '2', '1'], ['VEQ', '1', 'B', '2', '10']]
```

**Problem is**

If I try with `map1 = str(val).split('SomethingElse')[1].split(',')[0].strip()`

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Maria\Documents\temp.py", line 5, in <module>
    map1 = str(val).split('SomethingElse:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because 'SomethingElse' not matched or unavailable in that list..

I have tried Try & Except method but it makes my code worst, is there any way to modify above logic to store variable if available or else store variable with blank?

Expected output:

If I try with `map1 = modified search string logic`

> print(map1) must be blank instead of giving index error.

Comment: `map1 = str(val).split('SomethingElse')[1].split(',')[0].strip()` here when you are doing `str(val).split('SomethingElse')` it returns an empty list and the you are trying to access the `1th` location of the list thats why you are getting the error. try to check for `length` of the `list` before accessing value of a particular index.

Comment: There is no need to call `str`: `val` is already a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code . The if checks if somethingElse is present in your string or initialise the string as empty

```
map2 = str(val).split('SomethingElse')[1].split(',')[0].strip()if \
                        "SomethingElse" in str(val) else \
                        ("")
map2
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To handle the case of the `split` value not existing you can do:

```
map1 = (str(val).split('SomethingElse') + [''])[1].split(',')[0].strip()
```

The key element being:

```
str(val).split('SomethingElse') + ['']
```

This insures that the list is at least two elements long.

Comment: thanks a lot.. this simple tip helps my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In a cleaner way, you can convert each `val` to a dictionary by splitting first by `", "` and then by `":"`:

```
d = dict(x.split(":") for x in val.split(", "))
# e.g., {'sequence': '1', 'MAP': 'A', 'num1': '1', 
#        'num2': '2', 'num3': '3'}
```

Then you can check if both `"MAP"` and `"num1"` are in the dictionary:

```
if "MAP" in d and "num1" in d:
    Y.append(['VEQ', '1', d["MAP"], '2', d["num1"]])
```

Naturally, `"MAP"` can be replaced with `"SomethingElse"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to search for 'MAP' and 'num1' keywords in the string. Then get their corresponding values.

**Code:**

```
import re

X = [
    'sequence:1, MAP: A, num1:1, num2:2, num3:3',
    'sequence:2, num1:10, num2:20, MAP: B, num3:30'
]

Y = []

for data in X:
    # Match 'MAP' in sting and get the corresponding value for 'MAP'
    map1 = re.match(r".*MAP:\s*(\S+),", data).group(1)
    # Match 'num1' in sting and get the corresponding value for 'num1'
    num1 = re.match(r".*num1:\s*(\S+),", data).group(1)
    Y.append(['VEQ','1', map1,'2', num1])


print(Y)
```

**Result:**

```
[['VEQ', '1', 'A', '2', '1'], ['VEQ', '1', 'B', '2', '10']]
```